# SlidingMenu broken on orientation change from landscape to portrait

Tags: android, slidingmenu

For my application I use the github library SlidingMenu from jfeinstein10. The implementation was not really difficult. However, I ran into an issue regarding the orientation. Because when the application is started in landscape and the device is rotated to portrait, the SlidingMenu is broken. A grey overlay is visible on the left and when I slide out the menu, it is displayed on the right side of the screen instead of left and there is no content.

I already reported this issue on Github: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/297

Can somebody help me to solve the issue?

Edit: important detail is that orientation changes are handled by my Activity in onConfigurationChange.

Screenshots:
[image: Screenshot 1: grey overlay]
[image: Screenshot 2: menu on the right instead of left]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a workaround. Here is a link to my workaround as described on Github: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/297#issuecomment-13941430

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in one of GitHub answers try to to reinitialize the SlidingMenu in the onConfigurationChanged.

Also don't forget to `removeAllViews()` on both the *parent* and *decorView*

Comment: Thnx for your answer. However, it doesn't quite work yet as I now have issues with the system bar after rotation. I updated the issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple fix that might work for you guys: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/297#issuecomment-21372380